# Way to handle namepace collision of $modal provider of angular-ui "modal" and angular-strap "aside"

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-strap

I was wondering if anyone knew a way (short of modifying angular-strap.js) that I can reconcile the $modal provider collision between angular-ui modal and anglular-strap "aside" (which uses the $modal provider)?  Currently if I try to use both, only one will work.

Possibly making things more complicated, I'm using the modalService https://github.com/m-e-conroy/angular-dialog-service that wraps angular-ui's modal control.